# Filebeat Script Processor Functions?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Is it possible to have the filebeat script processor call functions from the main event function?
The idea would be to call function X from the main event function if the field was an object or value was equal to 5 (ie some event happened and needed special processing). Therefore, function X would do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, here's a snippet showing how it was done:

```
  - script:
      lang: javascript
      id: get_fields
      source: > 
        function check(event, field){
            event.Append("fieldAppender", field);
        }
        function process(event) {
            var a = event.Get();
            for( var field in a){
                 check(event, field);
            }
        }
```